# Do you use he/she or it to refer to ghost?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

If I have a sentence:

> There are many stories which have been told about a ghost that haunted this castle. 
>   Strangely, ... (the ghost) has never appeared in front of my face for 10 years.

I notice that when it comes to "spirit, dark force", many people use "it" instead of making it personalized by using "she/he" as the subject pronoun.

Should I use the subject pronoun "he/she" or "it" to refer to the ghost?

Comment: Nice question!  :-)

Comment: "There are many stories have been told " needs correction, though.

Comment: "Do you use he/she or it when refer to animal?" is another one of these series of questions. The answer for all of them is it depends on context.

Comment: @Speedy: I don't see how "depends on context" makes it a stupid question. How does it depend on context? In what context would you use each pronoun?

Comment: @Kris: Namely, "There are many stories THAT have been told ..."

Comment: Also, "never appeared ... for ten years" is inconsistent. Did it never appear, or did it appear ten years ago but not since? Or do you mean that you have never seen it though you have been looking for ten years?

Comment: @Jay If we are speaking about the ghost of the woman it will be she, if we are speaking about the mother of the Bambi it will be she and ect...If we have lack of information it will be it.

Comment: @Jay Also, "Many stories have been told ..."

Comment: @Kris: Sure. I didn't mean to imply that my suggestion was the only possible valid wording.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there are any gender cues (e.g. *man* in *The Headless Horseman*) then you should certainly use *he* or *she*.

If you don't consider the ghost as being like a person, use *it*.

If you think of the ghost as being like a person but you don't know the gender, follow the rules for people of unknown gender: use *he*, *he/she*, *they* or *the ghost*.

Answer (score 3):

Even with gender cues, it depends on what you are trying to portray.  If you want to convey that the character [or narrator] sees the ghost as a non-human entity, or something too unreal, you should still say 'it'.  This could imply that the character is not going along with the ruse, whereas using he/she implies strongly that the character is in agreement that the encounter with a 'ghost' is authentic.

Comment: Good point. An official report might say "the apparition moved to the tombstone, where it seemed to make a low sound before vanishing", but only a believer would say "the grey lady drifted to her grave, where she moaned and disappeared."